# How to assign column names as first row with write.table?

Tags: r

I want to save the file based on the input format described [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/NormalyzerDE/inst/doc/vignette.pdf), where each column should start as a header. Example:

```
pepseq s1 s2 s3 s4
ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
AWAG 23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2
```

The data will be in the following format:

```
rawData <- as.matrix(utils::read.table(inputPath, 
                                               header=FALSE, 
                                               sep="\t", 
                                               stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                                               quote="",
                                               comment.char=""))
```

I prepared the input file using:

```
write.table(mat, "processed_data.csv", sep="\t", row.names=T, quote=F, col.names=F)
```

However, when I read the file using the following code, `rawData` does not have the column names from `mat`. I expect the column names of `mat` appears as the first row of `rawData` or as described in the expected input format above.

```
rawData <- as.matrix(utils::read.table("processed_data.csv", 
                                               header=FALSE, 
                                               sep="\t", 
                                               stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                                               quote="",
                                               comment.char=""))
```

Input:

```
> dput(mat[1:10,])
structure(c(0.772169167803547, 0.796725784447476, 0.260572987721692, 
0.506139154160982, 0.433833560709413, 0.489768076398363, 0.424283765347885, 
0.338335607094134, 0.448840381991814, 0.489768076398363, 0.612625538020086, 
0.466284074605452, 0.246771879483501, 0.436154949784792, 0.39454806312769, 
0.36154949784792, 0.327116212338594, 0.340028694404591, 0.341463414634146, 
0.671449067431851, 0.350267379679144, 0.588235294117647, 0.31951871657754, 
0.378342245989305, 0.371657754010695, 0.372994652406417, 0.31951871657754, 
0.438502673796791, 0.322192513368984, 0.512032085561497, 0.802600472813239, 
0.540189125295508, 0.340425531914893, 0.572104018912529, 0.358156028368794, 
0.434988179669031, 0.51063829787234, 0.540189125295508, 0.494089834515366, 
0.567375886524823, 0.468937875751503, 0.7374749498998, 0.258517034068136, 
0.442885771543086, 0.420841683366733, 0.338677354709419, 0.322645290581162, 
0.336673346693387, 0.318637274549098, 0.739478957915832, 0.795880149812734, 
0.552434456928839, 0.254681647940075, 0.51685393258427, 0.451310861423221, 
0.434456928838951, 0.49438202247191, 0.552434456928839, 0.49063670411985, 
0.524344569288389, 0.936073059360731, 0.640791476407915, 0.277016742770167, 
0.4779299847793, 0.388127853881279, 0.410958904109589, 0.410958904109589, 
0.372907153729072, 0.432267884322679, 0.605783866057839, 0.404309252217998, 
0.482889733840304, 0.129277566539924, 0.367553865652725, 0.160963244613435, 
0.311787072243346, 0.220532319391635, 0.280101394169835, 0.228136882129278, 
0.38276299112801), dim = c(10L, 8L), dimnames = list(c("AAAS", 
"AAK1", "AAMDC", "AARS", "AASDHPPT", "ABCD3", "ABCE1", "ABCF1", 
"ABHD10", "ABI1"), c("C_1", "C_2", "C_3", "C_4", "D_5", "D_6", 
"D_7", "D_8")))
```

Output:

`rawData`

```
> dput(rawData[1:10,])
structure(c("AAAS", "AAK1", "AAMDC", "AARS", "AASDHPPT", "ABCD3", 
"ABCE1", "ABCF1", "ABHD10", "ABI1", "0.7721692", "0.7967258", 
"0.2605730", "0.5061392", "0.4338336", "0.4897681", "0.4242838", 
"0.3383356", "0.4488404", "0.4897681", "0.61262554", "0.46628407", 
"0.24677188", "0.43615495", "0.39454806", "0.36154950", "0.32711621", 
"0.34002869", "0.34146341", "0.67144907", "0.35026738", "0.58823529", 
"0.31951872", "0.37834225", "0.37165775", "0.37299465", "0.31951872", 
"0.43850267", "0.32219251", "0.51203209", "0.80260047", "0.54018913", 
"0.34042553", "0.57210402", "0.35815603", "0.43498818", "0.51063830", 
"0.54018913", "0.49408983", "0.56737589", "0.468937876", "0.737474950", 
"0.258517034", "0.442885772", "0.420841683", "0.338677355", "0.322645291", 
"0.336673347", "0.318637275", "0.739478958", "0.79588015", "0.55243446", 
"0.25468165", "0.51685393", "0.45131086", "0.43445693", "0.49438202", 
"0.55243446", "0.49063670", "0.52434457", "0.93607306", "0.64079148", 
"0.27701674", "0.47792998", "0.38812785", "0.41095890", "0.41095890", 
"0.37290715", "0.43226788", "0.60578387", "0.40430925", "0.48288973", 
"0.12927757", "0.36755387", "0.16096324", "0.31178707", "0.22053232", 
"0.28010139", "0.22813688", "0.38276299"), dim = 10:9, dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9"
    )))
```

Comment: I'm confused, if you're expecting column names, why are you specifying `col.names = F` when writing the file and then `header = FALSE` when reading it?

Comment: I need the column names but the `as.matrix(utils::read.table...` function has `header=FALSE`. Hence, my workaround is to set `col.names=F` so that I can read into the function.

Comment: Where are you expecting the column names to come from if you specify that they are not to be written into the file, and not to be read back?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that they use the gene names as a column, whereas they should be row names. Technically the string `pepseq` at the beginning causes that.

```
 x <- 'pepseq s1   s2   s3   s4
       ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
       AWAG   23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
       ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2'
```

Whether we read it without header (the default)

```
(x1 <- read.table(text=x))
#       V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
# 1 pepseq   s1   s2   s3   s4
# 2 ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
# 3   AWAG 23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
# 4 ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2
```

or with header,

```
(x2 <- read.table(text=x, header=TRUE))
#   pepseq   s1   s2   s3   s4
# 1 ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
# 2   AWAG 23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
# 3 ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2
```

in each case, `as.matrix()` yields a matrix of mode `"character"` (`mode(as.matrix(x2))`), because the mode is defined by the data type of the first column.

```
as.matrix(x2)
#      pepseq   s1     s2     s3     s4    
# [1,] "ATAAGG" "20.0" "21.2" "19.4" "18.5"
# [2,] "AWAG"   "23.3" "24.1" "23.5" "17.3"
# [3,] "ACATGM" "22.1" "22.3" "22.5" "23.2"
```

Of course we could do

```
`rownames<-`(as.matrix(x2[, -1]), x2$pepseq)
#          s1   s2   s3   s4
# ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
# AWAG   23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
# ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2
```

to get a numeric matrix we can calculate with, but this is quite cumbersome.

If we delete the string `pepseq` (or don't use it in the first place), the gene names are interpreted as row names automatically,

```
 y <- 's1   s2   s3   s4
       ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
       AWAG   23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
       ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2'
```

and we can read the data very easily,

```
(rawData <- as.matrix(read.table(text=y)))
#          s1   s2   s3   s4
# ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
# AWAG   23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
# ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2
```

which is probably what you (justifiably) intended to do.

Even `write.table` and reading it back in using `read.table` can be used without setting any extra options.

```
write.table(rawData, file='foo.txt')

(as.matrix(read.table('foo.txt')))
#          s1   s2   s3   s4
# ATAAGG 20.0 21.2 19.4 18.5
# AWAG   23.3 24.1 23.5 17.3
# ACATGM 22.1 22.3 22.5 23.2
```

If we need the row names, we can still easily read them.

```
(gene_names <- rownames(rawData))
# [1] "ATAAGG" "AWAG"   "ACATGM"
```

Note, that row names (as well as column names) must be unique, but actually that is a great feature, since it protects against duplicates.

I am aware that there are packages/philosophies out there that use a first column rather than row names. As demonstrated this has unpleasant consequences, and personally I try to avoid them.